# Google Maps / jQuery - create object from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is a plunker of the google map that was working but after I get back from vacation it doesn't work anymore. But still you can look at the code more - https://plnkr.co/edit/jHCuVVhGDLwgjNw4bcLr

Here is the google maps code:

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.4357808, 4.991315699999973),
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}

var seg = {
    1: 'investment_cast',
    2: 'forged_Prod',
    3: 'air_Prod',
    5: 'worldwide',
    6: 'structurals'
}

var comp = {
    1: 'structurals',
    2: 'airfoils',
    3: 'wyman',
    4: 'energy',
    5: 'fasteners',
    6: 'struc_comp',
    7: 'mech_hard',
    8: 'engine_prod',
    9: 'corp',
    10: 'aero',
    12: 'timet',
    13: 'spec_metals'
}

var myJSON = {};
var myMarkers=[];

$.getJSON("locations.json", function(json1) {
    myJSON=json1;
    $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude); 
        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng
        });
        myMarkers[key]=marker;
        marker.setMap(map);

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            if (infoWindow) {infoWindow.close();}
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<h5>" + data.display_name + "</h5>" +
                "<div>" + data.street+ "</div>" +
                "<div>" + data.city + ", " + data.state + " &nbsp; " + data.postal_code + "</div>" +
                "<div class='mapPhoneNum'>" + data.telephone + "</div>" +
                "<a href=" + data.web_url + ">Website</a>"
            });
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            map.setZoom(15);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());

            google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow,'closeclick',function(){
              resetMapOrigin();
            });

        });

        filterMarkers = function(category){

            var component = category.data("component_id");
            var segment = category.data("segment_id")

            setMapOnAll(null);
            resetMapOrigin();

            var filteredMarkers=[];

            $.each(myJSON, function(key, data) {


                if( typeof(component)!="undefined" ){

                  if( (myJSON[key].component_id == component) && (myJSON[key].segment_id == segment) ){ 
                    filteredMarkers.push(key);
                  }

                }else{
                  if( myJSON[key].segment_id == segment ){
                    filteredMarkers.push(key);
                  }
                }
            });

            for(i=0;i<filteredMarkers.length;i++){
                myMarkers[filteredMarkers[i]].setMap(map);
            }
        }

        function setMapOnAll(map) {
            for (var i = 0; i < myMarkers.length; i++) {
                myMarkers[i].setMap(map);
            }
        }

        function resetMapOrigin(){
          map.setZoom(2);
          map.setCenter({lat:52.4357808,lng:4.991315699999973});
        }
    });

});
```

So the problem is that `var seg ={...}` and `var comp ={...}` are hard coded into an object. What I need to be able to do is use `$.getJSON` (or whatever else will work) to pull that data from a json file (like I'm doing with the locations.json) and format it exactly like the objects currently are `1: 'structurals', 2: 'airfoils', and so on` (I need to keep this structure).

The json files are formated like this -

Components:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "display_name": "structurals"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "display_name": "airfoils"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "display_name": "wyman"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "display_name": "energy"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "display_name": "fasteners"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "display_name": "struc_comp"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "display_name": "mech_hard"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "display_name": "engine_prod"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "display_name": "corp"
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "display_name": "aero"
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "display_name": "timet"
    },
    {
        "id": "13",
        "display_name": "spec_metals"
    }
]
```

Segments:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "display_name": "investment_cast"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "display_name": "forged_Prod"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "display_name": "air_Prod"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "display_name": "worldwide"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "display_name": "structurals"
    }
]
```

So How can I grab this JSON data from above and format it the same way that I currently have the "seg and comp" object formated? *(the filenames are components.json and segments.json)*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any questions about my answer below. Thanks

Comment: @agon024 you didn't even care to acknowledge any answer. This is wrong. People have put their valuable time helping you and you must respect that.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to iterate through the array of objects, and create another object with properties named by each id. This shows what I mean, assuming you have already fetched and parsed the json into an object:

```
var data = 
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "display_name": "investment_cast"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "display_name": "forged_Prod"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "display_name": "air_Prod"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "display_name": "worldwide"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "display_name": "structurals"
    }
];


var seg = {};
data.forEach( function(o) {
  var x = parseInt(o.id);
  seg[x] = o.display_name;
});

console.log(seg);
/*
{ '1': 'investment_cast',
  '2': 'forged_Prod',
  '3': 'air_Prod',
  '5': 'worldwide',
  '6': 'structurals' }
*/
```

Actually in practice, I might use a utility library like lodash to do this, say with keyBy():
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#keyBy

edit: keyBy() will not do exactly what you want, so ignore that part.

edit: in addition, if you are fetching 3 json files, those are async operations and so you will need to possibly combine the operations and wait until all the json fetches are done. Normally this would be done with a Promise in javascript (or a Promise library): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

For your question:

> How can I grab this JSON data from above and format it the same way that I currently have the "seg and comp" object formated?

You can use [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) for your other json files (i.e. *components.json* and *segments.json*), just like you are doing with the *locations.json* file. Because this leads to three asynchronous requests, it would be beneficial to wait until all are completed. [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and you can wait until all promises are done before adding locations to the map.

You could use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to run code after all promises are done, though it doesn't support IE. I looked for an equivalent jQuery function and found [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) (used with [.done()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)) after reading [this blog post](https://davidwalsh.name/write-javascript-promises) that mentions it. That technique appears to work:

```
$.when($.getJSON("locations.json"), $.getJSON("segments.json"),     
$.getJSON("components.json")).
    done(function(locationsResponse, segResponse, compResponse) {
   // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
    myJSON = locationsResponse[0];
    var seg = segResponse[0];
    var comp = compResponse[0];
    //rest of code to add markers to the map
    //...
});
```

When I looked at [your plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jHCuVVhGDLwgjNw4bcLr), I did notice an error in the browser console:

> script.js:79 Uncaught TypeError: category.data is not a function(…)

It appears that this is caused by the radio inputs calling the function *filterMarkers* and passing a string value instead of a reference to jQuery's selector for that input (i.e. `$(this)`). So you can update the inputs to all pass that reference and set the *data-component_id* and/or *data-segment_id* where appropriate. For example, the lines below:

```
      <div class="optGroup"><input onclick="filterMarkers($(this));" type="radio" name="loc" value="investment_cast" data-segment_id="2" data-component_id="3" /> Investment Cast Products</div>
      <div class="optChild"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="structurals" /> PCC Structurals</div>
      <div class="optChild"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="airfoils" /> PCC Airfoils</div>
```

Should be updated like this:

```
      <div class="optGroup"><input onclick="filterMarkers($(this));" type="radio" name="loc" value="investment_cast" data-segment_id="2" data-component_id="3" /> Investment Cast Products</div>
      <div class="optChild"><input onclick="filterMarkers($(this));" type="radio" name="loc" value="structurals" data-component_id="1" /> PCC Structurals</div>
      <div class="optChild"><input onclick="filterMarkers($(this));" type="radio" name="loc" value="airfoils" data-component_id="2" /> PCC Airfoils</div>
```

See [this updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/x10MnyvAmFD4GToc9XRJ?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plunker with required and refactored code changes **[Working Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/72JJu9aPFmKZoYzGJwIG?p=preview)** changes are in `scripts.js` file

**Explaning my code:**
The logic to build your required `seg` and `comp` from JSON data is to loop through your result and pick the data out of `id` and `display_name` as `key` & `value`.

```
function formatData(jsonData){
  var obj ={};
  jsonData.forEach(function(item,index){
    var key = parseInt(item.id,10);
    obj[key] = item.display_name;
  });
  return obj;
}
```

The above funciton takes your `json` data and returns back the formatted result in a object.

Next since you want all the data to be present upfront before you build your google map I would say lets load the data one by one and when we have all lets build the Map.

```
function GetAllDataSetsAndInititateMap() {
  $.getJSON("segments.json", function(json) {
    seg = formatData(json);
    $.getJSON("components.json", function(json) {
      comp = formatData(json);
      $.getJSON("locations.json", function(json) {
        myJSON = json;
          BuildMap();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Having these in place, Write a new function called `BuildMap` and place all your current code which is present inside the `$.getJSON("locations.json", function(json1) {` block.

Your `BuildMap` function will look like

```
function BuildMap(){
   var json1 = myJSON;
   $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
     // all the existing code.
   });
}
```

This has been tested and Here is a **[Working Example in Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/72JJu9aPFmKZoYzGJwIG?p=preview)** changes are in `scripts.js` file.

Hope this helps!!